# push-froward measure and change of variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure

let there exists two measurable space, $(\Omega,\sigma(\Omega),\mathbb{P})$ and $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{P_X})$, and $G\subset \mathbb{R}, X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$

$$\color{blue}{\mathbb{E}(G)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g\,d\mathbb{P_X}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}gf_X(x)\,dx}=\color{red}{\int_{\Omega}g\circ X(w)d\mathbb{P}}=\require{cancel} \xcancel{\int_{\Omega}g\circ X(w)\color{red}{\cdot} d\omega}$$

The blue part is what we usually encounter in the probability, but when I transfer back to sample space I struggle. I am not sure if my red part is correct. If so, I believe there should something at the **red dot**, but I don't know what it should be.$\int_{\Omega}g\circ X(w)\color{red}{\cdot} d\omega$

Comment: What is the connection between $g$ and $G$? $d\omega$ does not make sense.

Comment: The only meaning of $d\omega$ would be $dp(\omega)$. The probability measure is the only thing w.r.t which you should integrate

Comment: thank you for your reply. Here is where I also see $dw$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161350/measure-theoretic-definition-of-expectation

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $G=g(X)$

Comment: Usual is $\int g\circ XdP=\int (g\circ X)(\omega)dP(\omega)=\int g(X(\omega))dP(\omega)$. But sometimes it is written as: $\int g(X(\omega))P(d\omega)$. As if $P(d\omega)$ stands for the probability of infinitesimal small $d\omega$.

Comment: @drhab Why isn't $d\mathbb{P}(w)$ have a density like $d\mathbb{P_X}=f_X(x)dx$

Comment: @LJNG A probability measure $P$ can only have a density wrt some measure defined on the same measurable space. On space $(\Omega,\sigma(\Omega))$ there is no such underlying measure defined. On space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ we can use the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @drhab Thank you for your reply. For these two measurable spaces, isn't $\mathbb{P}$ the measure on $(\Omega,\sigma({\Omega}))$? there are two probability measure actually exists, one is on $\sigma({\Omega})$, the other is on $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Yes. $P$ on $\Omega$ is a probability space measure. The every random variable $X$ with domain $\Omega$ and codomain $\mathbb R$ generates a probability measure $P_X$ on $\mathbb R$. This measure is labeled as "the distribution of $X$" and might have a density wrt the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @drhab Then can I proceed to write $\int_\Omega g(X(\omega))d\mathbb{P}$ in terms of some integration wrt to  $dw$, and what is that integrand part? Is my right-most formula correct?

Comment: No. You cannot integrate wrt something like "$d\omega$". You can only integrate wrt a specific measure (which lacks in this context). Your right-most formula makes no sense.

Comment: @drhab Thank you so much for the clarification. Then, if the middle blue and red hold that equality? they are the same in different corresponding measurable spaces with different measures?

Comment: Yes. I have written an answer in the hope that it will make things more clear. Next to correctness also consistency in notation is important in mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer - or actually more an effort to make things clear - I have chosen to write $Y$ for $G$.

---

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\Bbb P)$ be a probability space and let $X$ denote a random variable defined on that space. Further let $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a Borel-measurable function.

Then also $Y:=g\circ X$ is a random variable and *by definition*:$$\mathbb EY=\int Yd\Bbb P=\int Y(\omega)d\mathbb P(\omega)\tag1$$
Random variable $Y$ generates (as *every* random variable does) a probability measure on measurable space $(\Bbb R,\mathcal B)$ (with $\mathcal B$ as notation for the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R$). This probability measure is usually denoted as $\Bbb P_Y$ and labeled as "distribution of $Y$". The following equality is well known:$$\mathbb EY=\int\mathsf{id}_{\Bbb R} d\Bbb P_Y=\int\mathsf{id}_{\Bbb R}(y)d\Bbb P_Y(y)=\int y d\Bbb P_Y(y)\tag2$$where $\mathsf{id}_{\Bbb R}$ denotes the identity function on $\Bbb R$ prescribed by $y\mapsto y$.

(**edit**: This equality can also be written as:$$\int\mathsf{id}_{\Bbb R}\circ Yd\Bbb P=\int\mathsf{id}_{\Bbb R}d\Bbb P_Y$$ and remains valid if the identity function is replaced by some other Borel-measurable function.)

A more common notation for the RHS is $\int y dF_Y(y)$ where $F_Y$ denotes the CDF of $Y$.

---

For random variable $X$ we can of course tell exactly the same story and the fact that $Y$ can be written as composition $g\circ X$ makes it possible to deduce the following equality:$$\Bbb EY=\mathbb Eg(X)=\int g d\mathbb P_X=\int g(x)d\mathbb P_X(x)=\int g(x)dF_X(x)$$
If moreover the distribution of $X$ has a density with respect to Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ then this function is usually denoted as $f_X(x)$ and we can write:$$\mathbb EY=\mathbb Eg(X)=\int gf_Xd\lambda=\int g(x)f_X(x)d\lambda(x)$$The RHS is usually abbreviated as $\int g(x)f_X(x)dx$ so then we end up with:$$\mathbb EY=\mathbb Eg(X)=\int g(x)f_X(x)dx$$

Comment: Thank you so much for this clarification. Just analogy the second equation, if the first equation can also be E(Y)=$\int1_{\Omega}d\mathbb{P}$ whereas the $1_{\Omega}$ is an indicator function

Comment: Note that $\int1_{\Omega}d\Bbb P=\Bbb P(\Omega)=1$ so we do *not* have $\Bbb EY=\int1_{\Omega}d\Bbb P$ in general. Maybe you meant to state that we have:$$\Bbb EY=\int1_{\Bbb R}\circ Yd\Bbb P=\int1_{\Bbb R}d\Bbb P_Y$$Note that $Y$ switches from integrand to measure.

Comment: Thank you for your post genuinely. You really saved my life !!!!!

Comment: Thank you for your post again, I've been retrieving this post and still found it useful. Since expectation can be written as integral w.r.t probability measure or distribution of the random variable, I am wondering regarding your last comment, if the probability of a set $E\subset\Omega$ can be written as w.r.t distribution of the random variable as well.  $\mathbb{P}(E)=\int\mathbf{1}_{E}\circ X^{-1}(\cdot)d\mathbb{P}_X$, I am not sure what $\cdot$ should be, and not sure if this equation useful?

Comment: First let me state that I might have spread some confusion. In my answer (and also my former comment) I wrote the *identity function* on $\mathbb R$ as "$1_{\mathbb R}$". This is not smart because it can easily be confused with the *indicator function* on $\mathbb R$. I repaired that by an edit of my question and now go for $\mathsf{id}_{\mathbb R}$. My comment is cannot be repaired but the equality in it should read as: $$\mathbb EY=\int\mathsf{id}_{\mathbb R}\circ Yd\mathbb P=\int\mathsf{id}_{\mathbb R}d\mathbb P_Y$$

Comment: You can write the probability of an event $E$ wrt a random variable $X$ iff $1_E=g(X)$ for some Borel measurable $g$. This is the case if e.g. $g=1_B$ for some Borel measurable set $B$. Then $\mathbb P(E)=\int 1_B(X)d\mathbb P=\mathbb P(X\in B)$ and this equals $\int1_Bd\mathbb P_X$.

Comment: aha, according to $\mathbf{1}_E=\mathbf{1}_B\circ X(w)$, if there is a measurable function map $E$ to the Borel set, my original equation $\mathbb{P}(E)=\int\mathbf{1}_E\circ X^{-1}(\omega)d\mathbb{P}_X$ seems correct?

Comment: Thank you so much！je uitleg lezen is beter dan tien jaar boeken lezen

Comment: The expression $1_E\circ X^{-1}$ requires a random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ that *has a measurable inverse* $X^{-1}:\mathbb R\to\Omega$. That phenomenom is quite "zeldzaam" (rare). If it exists then $1_E\circ X^{-1}=1_B$ so that its integral wrt $\mathbb P_X$ equals $\mathbb P_X(B)=\mathbb P(X\in B)=\mathbb P(E)$.