# please explain differences in the inner product of two functions in Hilbert and Lebesgue space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, lebesgue-measure, inner-products

Here are definition from wiki:

inner product for Hilbert space, two square-integrable real-valued functions $f$ and $g$ on an interval $[a, b]$
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int^a_b f(x)g(x)dx$$

inner product for Lebesgue space, consider $L_2(\Omega, \mu)$

$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{\Omega} f(x)g(x)d\mu(x)$$

1. Since $L_2$ is also Hilbert space so they should be the same, is $dx$ also a measure?
2. They are only differences in the domain wrt different $dx$ and $d\mu(x)$, and I thought it is change of variable problem, below is my motivation for this question  [push-froward measure and change of variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4401625/push-froward-measure-and-change-of-variable)

I am so confused about those, please help me to clarify.

---

**Extra  thoughts**

From Stein's real analysis I found: $$\|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(x)|^2dx$$

$$\|f\|_{L^2(X,\mu)}^2=\int_{X}|f(x)|^2d\mu$$

I guess they are really the same?

1. In $\mathbb{R}^d$ so the set is Riemann integrable, $dx$ itself read as already a measure. In contrast to $L^2(X,\mu)$ we need a Lebesgue measure.

If the above reasoning is correct, what guarantee $\mathbb{R}^d$ is Riemann integrable, I mean rational indication function is not Riemann integrable.

Please help me to clarify my thoughts

Comment: In the first example, $dx$ is Lebesgue measure. The first example is a special case (where $\Omega = [a,b]$) of the second example. I think that if $\mu$ is a “complete” measure then $L^2(\Omega,\mu)$ with the given inner product is a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the viewpoint of Lebesgue theory, $dx$ as you are used to it is an abbreviation for $dm(x)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Lebesgue theory also lets you integrate over other sets as long as you are considering real-, complex-, vector-, or even Banach space-valued functions on a measure space.

Comment: So the first one in $\mathbb{R}^d$ it is also Lebesgue integral not Riemann integral?

Comment: @LJNG Yes, although if the Riemann and Lebesgue integral both exist then they are the same.